# WebView opens link, then opens in browser

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView that is opening a Url for an article. However, a couple of seconds after opening the link in the WebView, the browser opens up and loads the same article.
This is my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_headline_web_view);

Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri headlineUri = intent.getData();

WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.loadUrl(headlineUri.toString());
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you add:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_headline_web_view);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri headlineUri = intent.getData();

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    webView.loadUrl(headlineUri.toString());
}

public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm no, it still opens the browser after about 2 seconds in the webView activity...

Comment: After looking at http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html it seems you might need to return false in shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Comment: My mistake, after reading through the docs that you posted I noticed I missed adding the `webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());`